# How to identify each edit text field in Selenium if all their Xpath are same

Tags: java, button, xpath, selenium-webdriver, textfield

I'm trying to pass values in 8 text fields in selenium using java. But when I take their xpath, it's same for all the 8 text fields. How can I enter values in it, by identifying each field separately ? Also there are 3 'Save' buttons in this page, with same xpaths. How can I identify them separately?
            Below is my code (with same xpath for 8 text fields and 'Save' buttons):

```
        //Enter values in 8 textfields
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("aaa");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("aaa");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("bbb");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("ccc");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("ddd");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("eee");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("fff");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']")).sendKeys("fff");

           //Click on 'Save' button
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='submit']")).click();
           Thread.sleep(10000);

            //Enter recepient
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='receipient_add']")).click();

            //click 'Save' button below recipient
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='submit']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
    ***HTML****
    Relevant section of the text field:

<document>
<html class="js" lang="en" dir="ltr" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body class="not-front logged-in page-manage-listing-agent no-sidebars tableHeader-processed">
<!-- wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- container -->
<div id="container">
<!-- page_wrapper -->
<div id="page_wrapper">
<!-- page -->
<div id="page">
<!-- page-header -->
<div id="page-header" class="style_float">
<!--end page-header -->
<div class="clear"/>
<!-- main menu -->
<div class="style_main_menu">
<!--end main menu -->
<div class="clear"/>
<div id="subheading" class="style_flow">
<div class="clear"/>
<!-- center -->
<div id="center" class="style_center_content_default">
<!-- content above -->
<div class="style_content_above_wrapper">
<!-- end content above -->
<!-- left side bar -->
<div id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar">
<!--end left side bar -->
<div class="style_content_main_wrapper">
<div id="content-main">
<!-- error message -->
<div class="error-message "/>
<!-- content help -->
<div class="content-help"/>
<div class="clear-block">
<h3 class="style_sub_title"/>
<form id="rmls-manage-agent-listing" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4756/7/Next">
<div>
<h3 class="style_sub_title">Tour Activity Status</h3>
<input id="edit-step" type="hidden" value="8" name="step"/>
<div class="container-inline-date form-item date-clear-block">
<div class="container-inline-date form-item date-clear-block">
<div class="form-submit-button">
<input id="form-nyo3QvZDdsqgPcIa0hMiityFWDw-jdMA6XuYvJU7aMU" type="hidden" value="form-nyo3QvZDdsqgPcIa0hMiityFWDw-jdMA6XuYvJU7aMU" name="form_build_id"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-manage-agent-listing-form-token" type="hidden" value="f18fc36d4d750ae3912d9cc941aa5c72" name="form_token"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-manage-agent-listing" type="hidden" value="rmls_manage_agent_listing" name="form_id"/>
<table class="sticky-header" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 605px; left: 480px; visibility: hidden;">
<table class="statistic_table sticky-enabled sticky-table">
<div id="style_activity_text" class="style_sub_title_two">Premium Placements</div>
<div id="">
<form id="rmls-activity-report-placement-list-form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4756/7/Next">
<div>
<div class="placement_save">
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24798" type="hidden" value="24798" name="placement24798"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title1.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24798" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24799" type="hidden" value="24799" name="placement24799"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title8.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24799" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24800" type="hidden" value="24800" name="placement24800"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title2.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24800" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24801" type="hidden" value="24801" name="placement24801"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title7.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24801" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24802" type="hidden" value="24802" name="placement24802"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title3.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24802" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24803" type="hidden" value="24803" name="placement24803"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title6.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24803" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24804" type="hidden" value="24804" name="placement24804"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title4.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24804" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_div">
<input id="edit-placement24805" type="hidden" value="24805" name="placement24805"/>
<img class="placement-images" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_list/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/stat-images/news-title5.jpg"/>
<div class="placement_txt_div">
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24805" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="placement_radio_div">
</div>
<div class="placement_submit_div">
<input id="form-mLn9X6UrPnGLa0cYCdxkBN3crwQzf-Cw5zU0lnbVufU" type="hidden" value="form-mLn9X6UrPnGLa0cYCdxkBN3crwQzf-Cw5zU0lnbVufU" name="form_build_id"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-list-form-form-token" type="hidden" value="4305d09bc8205b6d0db44711023395c9" name="form_token"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-list-form" type="hidden" value="rmls_activity_report_placement_list_form" name="form_id"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="style_sub_title_two">Custom Placements</div>
<a class="custom-placement-link" href="/%2523">Add New</a>
<div id="activity_report_placement_form_div" style="display:none;">
<form id="rmls-activity-report-placement-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/manage-listing-agent/4756/7/Next">
<div>
<div id="placement_title-wrapper" class="form-item">
<div id="placement_link-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label for="placement_link">Link: </label>
<input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="placement_link" maxlength="255"/>
</div>
<div id="edit-thumb-wrapper" class="form-item">
<input id="edit-placement-listing-id" type="hidden" value="4756" name="placement_listing_id"/>
<input id="submit" class="form-submit bluebutton" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>
<input id="form-mCvTeIxSSPEq5qAcjv0ROjiJVvl2JV0fVIoWj9tQ0a8" type="hidden" value="form-mCvTeIxSSPEq5qAcjv0ROjiJVvl2JV0fVIoWj9tQ0a8" name="form_build_id"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-form-form-token" type="hidden" value="185635f8c3122f16a07b5b626e7fc473" name="form_token"/>
<input id="edit-rmls-activity-report-placement-form" type="hidden" value="rmls_activity_report_placement_form" name="form_id"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="">
</div>
</form>
<div id="dialog-manage-listing"/>
</div>
<!-- content main -->
<!-- right side bar -->
<!-- end right side bar -->
</div>
<!-- style_content_main_wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- center -->
<div class="clear"/>
<div id="footer">
</div>
<!--end page -->
</div>
<!--end page_wrapper -->
<div id="dialog"/>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!-- var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-37131766-1"]);_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);(function() {var ga = document.createElement("script");ga.type = "text/javascript";ga.async = true;ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})(); //--><!]]> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!-- jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "CToolsAJAX": { "scripts": { "/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.min.js": true, "/misc/drupal.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/blockui/jquery.blockUI.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/blockui/blockui.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/block_edit/block_edit.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/google_analytics/googleanalytics.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/superfish.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.core.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.dialog.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.draggable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.droppable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.sortable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/js/rmls.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/clippy/jquery.clippy.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.datepicker.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/lib/jquery.timeentry.pack.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/date_popup.js": true, "/misc/tableheader.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.form.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/ctools/js/ajax-responder.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/ui/minified/ui.resizable.min.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/dialog/dialog.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls_order_verification/custom.js": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls_order_verification/modal-window.min.js": true }, "css": { "/modules/node/node.css": true, "/modules/system/defaults.css": true, "/modules/system/system.css": true, "/modules/system/system-menus.css": true, "/modules/user/user.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/block_edit/block_edit.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/cck/theme/content-module.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/date/date_popup/themes/jquery.timeentry.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/filefield/filefield.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus_default.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/themes/default/ui.all.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/jquery_ui/jquery.ui/themes/default/ui.datepicker.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_attribute/uc_attribute.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_order/uc_order.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_product/uc_product.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_store/uc_store.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/cck/modules/fieldgroup/fieldgroup.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/rmls.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/style.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/grid.css": true, "/sites/all/themes/rmls_webtheme/order_verification.css": true, "/sites/all/modules/rmls_order_verification/modal-window.css": true } } }); //--><!]]> </script>
</div>
<!--end container -->
</div>
<!--end wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"61afc6e03f","applicationID":"10285903","transactionName":"ZwQAMUZYW0QAAkZaDF5OIwZAUFpZThNfXxBvDAMLVV5QaAAGV10Xbw0LFkBQW1A+B11BDm8WEARESVBF","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":8493,"atts":"S0MDRw5CSEo=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Comment: Please add the html.

Comment: @Guy: Sorry, I'm totally new to this. From where can I get the Html?

Comment: How did you get the `xpath` you used?

Comment: @ Guy: Right clicked that element and took 'Inspect in FirePath', from here I got the Xpath of each element. (In firefox)

Comment: The xml structure you see there is the html. Post here the part you want to interact with

Comment: @ Guy: For Text fields:: <input id="placement_link" class="form-text" type="text" value="" size="60" name="link24798" maxlength="255"/>                                                  
and for Buttons:: <input id="submit" class="form-submit bluebutton" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit"/>

Comment: All the text fields looks exactly like that? are you sure? id should be unique.

Comment: @Guy: Yup..all fields looks exactly  the same. IDs are unique

Comment: Can you please add to your question the entire relevant section of the text fields? you can do it by click on the edit link under the bottom left corner of the question.

Comment: You posted the Java code again, I was talking about the html structure.

Comment: @Guy: Now please check.

Comment: The entire section please. I know I'm bugging you but I can't help you with only partial information.

Comment: Including their parent tags please.

Comment: @ Guy: Please check the question now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below:

```
//i take string array for eight text field input value
String [] textToInput = {"first","second","Third","Fourth","Fifth","Sixth","Seventh","Eight"};

List<WebElement> elements =  driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='placement_link']"));

System.out.println("size is "+elements.size());

for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++){
        elements.get(i).sendKeys(textToInput[i]);
    }
```

u can click on save button in same way.

Comment: @Guy: Now the values got entered for each textfields, but its showing like this in the console:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at Production.AdLinkComplete.main(AdLinkComplete.java:69) .
What might be the issue?

Comment: @Guy: how can I do it for click action (Save button). Now I need not pass any value here right, like 'textToInput' . So, how can I implement the click action for buttons with same xpath here?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means problem in your array size. your string array and/or elements array size is mismatch. pls check the both size and the loop by debug.

Comment: for save button click, take elements using save button path and inside loop, just use  elements.get(i).click(). no need to enter any text as this is a save button.

Comment: Actually the location of first 'Save' button is below the 8 text fields and the second 'Save button' is coming after entering other details (at the botton of the page). How can I detect and click them in this case? There is nothing in the 'Button' html that differentiates them in the xpath (neither class/id/type/name/value).

Comment: to click first save, use saveElements.get(0).click(); for second one, use saveElements.get(1).click()